# python create list comprehension with variable assignment and no duplicated

Tags: python

I'm looping over a function in my script which returns list of lists, for example in the first iteration I'm getting the following list of lists:

```
list1 = [['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat nterprise Linux,Premium', 1]]
```

What I want to get is a list with distinct items, and summary of numbers for each subscriptions, i.e for standard list = 1+1 =2  for premium list 1+1=2

```
list2 = ['Farm05','Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard',2]
list3 = ['Farm05','Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium',2]
```

I have tried this approach, but it's not removing the duplicates and it doesn't look clean. How can I achieve it with list comprehentions?

```
new_list = []
    for i in Farm:
        farm = i[0]
        subscription = i[1]
        count = i[2]
        count += count
        if farm not in list1 or subscription not in list1 or count  not in list1:
            new_list.extend(farm,subscription,count)
```

Comment: You mean it is same for all but the last items?

Comment: you seem to have 3 *standard* subscriptions

Comment: besides 3 standard subscriptions you have on 1 "Enterprise"... the other is "nterprise"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`groupby` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). And here is how you can use it:

```
from itertools import groupby    

res = [[*i, sum(k[-1] for k in g)] for i, g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x[:-1])]
```

which for the example input you provided<sup>1</sup> prints:

```
[['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 3], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 2]]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*The input had to be corrected; it contained typos.*

Comment: I like the `groupby` idea, though it would fail if the identical (farm, subscription) aren't grouped in the original data - which maybe is the case, the OP didn't tell us. Also, the `*i` syntax as used here is only valid from Python 3.5 on. The alternative for older versions would be `i[0], i[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension to all you need probably won't make it very readable.

A cleaner way to do it would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], 
         ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], 
         ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], 
         ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 1], 
         ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 1]]

# We create a dict whose keys will be (farm, subscription) tuples, 
# and whose default values will be 0
summary = defaultdict(int)

for elt in list1:
    farm, sub, count = elt
    summary[(farm, sub)] += count

print(summary)
#   defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard'): 3, 
# ('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium'): 2})


print(summary[('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard')])
# 3
```

If you really want a list in the format of your question:

```
out = [[key[0], key[1], total] for  key, total in summary.items()]
print(out)
# [['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 3], 
# ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 2]]
```

It would be even nicer with a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for elt in list1:
    farm, sub, count = elt
    counts.update({(farm, sub): count})

print(counts)
# Counter({('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard'): 3, ('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium'): 2})

print(counts.most_common(1))
# [(('Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard'), 3)]

# and you can get the output in the format of the question just as before, with:
out = [[key[0], key[1], total] for  key, total in counts.items()]
print(out)
# [['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 3], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to do this with a dictionairy:

```
list1 = [['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium', 1], ['Farm05', 'Red Hat nterprise Linux,Premium', 1]]
result = {}

for e in list1:
    index = ', '.join([e[0].strip(), e[1].strip()])
    if index in result:
        result[index] = result[index] + e[2]
    else:
        result[index] = e[2]

# do something with the result
for i, v  in enumerate(result):
    print(i, v, result[v])
```

output:

```
0 Farm05, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Standard 3
1 Farm05, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Premium 1
2 Farm05, Red Hat nterprise Linux,Premium 1
```

NOTE: the input `list1` is likely to contain two typo's in the OP's original question, this is why the output is showing like this. The typo's are likely in the last element "`['Farm05', 'Red Hat nterprise Linux,Premium', 1]`"

- First Typo is likely to be "nterprise" and should be "Enterprise"
- Second Typo is likely the missing space after the comma

You should either write code to 'catch' typo's on the input, or fix the input